# Memory management and properties (init/dealloc)

Tags: ios, memory-management, properties

Until yesterday I thought I understood how properties memory management works, but then I ran an "Analize" task with XCode and got plenty of "This object is not own here". Here is a simple example that describes my problem :

MyObservingObject.h:

```
@interface MyObservingObject : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *observedDictionary;
-(id)initWithDictCapacity:(int)capacity;
@end
```

MyObservingObject.m:

```
@synthesize observedDictionary;

-(id)initWithDictCapacity:(int)capacity {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.observedDictionary = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:capacity] autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // The following line makes the Analize action say :
    // "Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"
    [self.observedDictionary release], self.observedDictionary=nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

What I don't understand is **Why should I leave this property without calling** `release` **on it?** My `@property` is set as `retain` (`copy` does the same), so when I'm doing `self.myRetainProperty = X`, then X got its retain count increased (it's owned by self), didn't it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It did get increased, but when you set it to `nil`, the setter method first releases the backing instance variable, and only then does it retain and assign the new value. Thus setting the **property** to `nil` is enough, setting the **ivar** to `nil` leaks memory, though.

For your better understanding: the typical implementation of an autogenerated retaining setter is equivalent to something like

```
- (void)setFoo:(id)foo
{
    if (_foo != foo) {
        [_foo release];
        _foo = [foo retain];
    }
}
```

Also note that, as a consequence, you should never release properties like this. If you do so, the backing ivar may be deallocated, and messaging it (`release` by the accessor when setting the property to `nil` afterwards) can crash.

Comment: But `[_myProperty release], _myProperty=nil` is correct, right ? With the iVar

Comment: This answer although correct does not address the actual reason for compiler warning. The bigger issue to understand is that the user is calling `release` on an object they do not own - see my answer for expansion.

Comment: @Paul.s My answer and the explanation *implies* that the released object is not owned by the caller. OP needed to understand the issue through an example, and not necessarily using a "technical" or language-lawyer explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should let the setter do the releasing for you, so remove the call to `release` in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    self.observedDictionary=nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

This is because the setter will be synthensized to something like:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object
{
    [object retain];
    [_object release];
    _object = object;
}
```

Which will work as desired when you pass in `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do

```
[self.observedDictionary release]
```

before

```
self.observedDictionary=nil;
```

This is enough, because this is a property, and it will automatically send release to previous value

```
self.observedDictionary=nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the compiler warning is because of the way you are retrieving the object.

By calling

```
[self.observedDictionary release];
```

you are in fact going through the accessor method defined as

```
- (NSDictionary *)observedDictionary;
```

This returns your object but due to the naming of `observedDictionary` the compiler assumes that there is no transfer of ownership e.g. the callee will not have to release this object unless they take a further retain. It is because of this that the compiler thinks you are going to do an overrelease by releasing an object that you don't actually own.

More specifically the convention for method names that transfer ownership is for them to start with `copy`, `mutableCopy`, `alloc` or `new`.

### Some examples

Here I have used a name that does not imply transfer for ownership so I get a warning

```
- (id)object;
{
  return [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
//=> Object leaked: allocated object is returned from a method whose name ('object') does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy', 'alloc' or 'new'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa
```

Fix 1: (don't transfer ownership)

```
- (id)object;
{
  return [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Fix 2: (make the name more appropriate)

```
- (id)newObject;
{
  return [[NSObject alloc] init];
}
```

With this knowledge we can of naming convention we can see that the below is wrong because we do not own the returned object

```
[self.object release]; //=> Produced warnings
```

And to show a final example - releasing an object that implies ownership transfer with it's name

```
[self.newObject release]; //=> No Warning
```